# EXCEL Formula issue of COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dataset, countif, worksheet-function

How  can I find values between two numbers in excel when we apply `COUNTIFS` formula.

For example if I have a column in which there are three values failed, passed & canceled & the rows are 1 to 9000. How can I find no. of successful in 1000 to 4999?

I am applying formula to the column & its not giving me the exact results. I did find it for the first question which was less than 1000 via

```
=COUNTIFS(Crowdfunding!$G:$G,Crowdfunding!$D:$D,"<1000")
```

How I can find the rest?

```
Less than 1000
1000 to 4999
5000 to 9999
10000 to 14999
15000 to 19999
20000 to 24999
25000 to 29999
30000 to 34999
35000 to 39999
40000 to 44999
45000 to 49999
Greater than or equal to 50000
```

What can I put in the formula?

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(Crowdfunding!$G:$G,Crowdfunding!$D:$D,">=1000" , Crowdfunding!$D:$D,"<5000")` etc

Comment: You need criteria for every range you pass to `COUNTIFS`. You haven't supplied criteria for column G.